# scrollTo desktop and mobile versions

Tags: javascript, mobile

In my desktop version, it scrolls to the `<div>` element that I want.

In my mobile version, it does not; it scrolls to the beginning of the page.

My code:

```
function getElementTop ( Elem )
{
    var elem;
    var yPos;
    var tempEl;

    if ( document.getElementById )
    {
        elem = document.getElementById ( Elem );
    }
    else if ( document.all )
    {
        elem = document.all[Elem];
    }

    yPos = elem.offsetTop;
    tempEl = elem.offsetParent;

    while ( tempEl != null )
    {
        yPos += tempEl.offsetTop;
        tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
    }

    return yPos;
}

var posicion = getElementTop("loaderId");
window.location.hash = value;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/))
{
    window.setTimeout(function () { window.scrollTo(0, posicion); }, 0);
}
else
{
    window.scrollTo(0, posicion);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the `setTimeout()` method to delay your call to `window.scrollTo()` ?

Comment: yes, I did it to wait load the page completely and that there I was positioned on the desired element

Comment: Why to check if `getElementById` exists? It's been around for 20 years or so ... Have you checked the value `getElementTop` returns?

Comment: @lbarrios1985 Try `window.setTimeout(function () { window.scrollTo(0, getElementTop("loaderId")); }, 0);`

Comment: @aaron its not working

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My problem is that the screen should be positioned on a <div> Specifically, (in this case 'loaderId') in desktop versions works perfectly, but mobiles versions is positioned at the top of the page. the scrollTo does not work in the mobiles versions